# How to automatically upload a pdf without the need of an user choosing it?

Tags: c#, pdf, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a blank pdf into a specific folder to do some type of "undo" to an action. What this do is to "re-paste" an ADS that was in a PDF with a blank pdf so it feels like an undo action.

The problem is simple, yet, I cannot find a simple solution.

Right now, my C# controller do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Upload(int? chunk, string name,int InsertionID)
{
    try
    {
        var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
        var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        chunk = chunk ?? 0;

        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, InsertionID.ToString()), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }
}
```

That works ok because "var fileUpload = Request.File[0];" takes the file that it needs from an HTML5 uploader called from JQuery. In this case, I need to do exactly the same, but RequestFiles should automatically take the file from a path and without any prompt (actually, the pdf would reside at the solution path).

I cannot pass a string to Request.Files like this? Request.Files["C:\file.pdf"] can I? Because I tried it and it doesn't work.

Can someone help or point me into the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Of course you can't. If it was possible then a website may be able to overwrite (silently) our documents...

Comment: "Our documents"?? I need to overwrite documents IN MY OWN App_Data folder of MY OWN VS solution. Then, that document is uploaded to a database. Perhaps I can create a PDF file on the fly with iTextSharp and do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FileSystemWatcher`... optionally add something to the FileName to give you more info.. . if not use a PDF Library to examine the contents and do the needful~

Comment: With that class I can put a watch into a specific path... as I'm reading at MSDN but I can't find where exactly this can help me out... :/

Comment: Because the user wouldn't have to select it?